# Sending illegal value to server

Tags: php, mysql, security, firebug, server-side

My form has a drop down list for state names. When the user submits the form, it sends it to my php script which in turn, adds it to my mysql database.

If a user changes the state value with firebug and submits it, it doesn't work because my database doesn't support foreign keys.

One solution is comparing received state with the state table.
(It is not only field, there is country, city, birthyear, job etc...)

does everyone know another solution?

Comment: hi alexy. you change my question  completely.(How could this be fixed?)???

Comment: I don't believe I changed your question completely (I.E it still has the same meaning).  I posted a response.

Comment: thank u for edit and response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One solution is comparing received state with the state table.

Comment: what if i copy allowed state values to array and check with in_arary()? i have any fields like state so checking take a long time?

Comment: @a.v you have said it all. not array but table. compare it with the state table.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

When the user submits the value (state name) it has an internal index (an id value for the html element).  Then, check with your database to find the state name that matches the index number.

> what if i copy allowed state values to array and check with in_arary()?

You could do that too.  Make sure you do it with the php script and not javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

A) validate your input before adding it to the db
B) use an enum

Comment: what if i copy allowed state values to array and check with in_arary()?

Comment: It depends how often your state data (and others) will change. If it's pretty fixed, i'd just store the possible values in code and validate against them to avoid unnecessary trips to the db. If the possible values are likely to change, then by all means store them in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Dont directly insert data to database...Before you fire insert query,,,first check whether that values is exist in the master table or not...
If the value in exist in master table then only fire insert query to your desire table..

Comment: what if i copy allowed state values to array and check with in_arary()?